# Css Pop-out Effect

Tags: css, elementor

[image]

How Can I achieve this with html & css?

I have a png image position absolute inside a div. But if I set the Div to overflow-hidden then the top part will also hide.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by doing a container, setting it relative to avoid the elements overflow, and positioning both as absolute to the bottom.

It would look like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 95px;
  height:70px;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  border: 2px solid darkblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.person {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px; /* same pixels than border */
  left: 10px; /* To make it simple and avoid your image overlaps the border, define same than border-radius of .box */
  width: 90px;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Replace svg for img if you are using the img tag */
.person svg {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="person">
  
    <!-- Replace this SVG for the image of your preference -->
    <svg viewBox="0 0 122.88 110.44"><path d="M46.07,68.62a19.25,19.25,0,0,1-1.63-2c-1.2-1.65-2.33-3.37-3.42-5.1L35.6,52.89c-2.06-3-3.14-5.74-3.14-7.91s1.23-5,3.68-5.63a149.33,149.33,0,0,1-.21-15.61,19.7,19.7,0,0,1,.65-3.58,20.63,20.63,0,0,1,9.21-11.7,23.65,23.65,0,0,1,5-2.39c3.15-1.19,1.63-6,5.1-6.07C64-.21,77.33,6.73,82.53,12.36a20.56,20.56,0,0,1,5.31,13.33l-.33,14.2a4,4,0,0,1,2.93,2.92c.43,1.74,0,4.12-1.52,7.48h0c0,.11-.11.11-.11.22L82.63,60.7c-1.4,2.3-2.85,4.65-4.48,6.81-1.93,2.58-3.52,2.12-1.87,4.59,11.83,16.26,46.6,6,46.6,38.34H0C0,78.08,34.78,88.36,46.6,72.1c1.36-2,1-1.85-.53-3.48Z"></path></svg>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Caveat that your images will need to be high quality PNGs with transparent backgrounds for this to work correctly.